# RegEx for passing all chars except a list of chars

Tags: javascript, regex

I want a pattern that contains all characters except English and Persian numbers. I found this pattern but my problem is how can I do against this pattern.

For example contains * and / and ... but not contains 1 2 3 ۱ ۲ ۳.

This pattern gets all numbers:

```
^[\u0600-\u06FF\s0-9]+$
```

Comment: I think, if I’m reading – and understanding – your question correctly, that you need: `^[^\u0600-\u06FF\s0-9]+$` (note the `^` character added to the character groups, to specify a “NOT”).

Comment: @DavidThomas ot works but doesnt still get all chars like an alphabet in persian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should works

```
/[^\d۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹]/g
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Y2lMiI/3/)

*Note: If I forget some Persian digits just add it before `]`*

Answer (score 1):

We might be able to solve this problem by adding our undesired unicodes in a char list, then swiping everything else, which I'm unsure if <kbd>space</kbd> would be undesired or not.

Maybe, something like this with modification would work:

```
([\s\S].*?)([\x{0600}-\x{06FF}0-9]+)?
```

#### Demo

We would just replace x with u for JavaScript:

```js
const regex = /([\s\S].*?)([\u{0600}-\u{06FF}0-9]+)?/gmu;
const str = `everthing we wish to have before 1 2 3 ۱ ۲ ۳ and everything else we wish to have`;
const subst = `$1`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

[image]

#### RegEx

If this wasn't your desired expression, you can modify/change your expressions in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/r2trXl/1/).

Answer (score 0):

This is not Ascii, nor Persian numbers

`[^0-9\u06F0-\u06F9]+`

Comment: @sin thank u it s work and ok bu i have a little problem  . this regex contains all char but it doesnt contain some unicode in persian consecutive like رگا

Comment: @sinak - So ah, not only did Pablo duplicate my exact regex an hour later, but you accepted it as the answer. https://regex101.com/r/pGp89H/1  To answer your question `this regex contains all char but it doesnt contain some unicode in persian consecutive like رگا ` It does match these characters, so am not sure what you're talking about. `\u0627    ا    ARABIC LETTER ALEF
\u0631    ر    ARABIC LETTER REH
\u06AF    گ    ARABIC LETTER GAF` https://regex101.com/r/HZkY4m/1